# DATE_FORMAT not picking my format in mysql

Tags: mysql

this is my query (Not Working): `SELECT date_format('21-Oct-19 15:59','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') + interval 3 day, date_format(now(), '%d-%b-%y %H:%i')`

this is my query (Working): `SELECT '2019-10-21 15:59' + interval 3 day, date_format(now(), '%d-%b-%y %H:%i')`

My data is in this format `21-Oct-19 15:59` i want to add 3 day in it. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a datetime in a non-standard format (that is, non YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), you need to convert it to a standard datetime using `STR_TO_DATE()`.

You used `DATE_FORMAT()` which does the opposite — it only accepts a standard datetime, and you can format a non-standard datetime.

You also need a different format specifier corresponding to the non-standard datetime input. You don't need to specify the output format for `STR_TO_DATE()`. It always outputs standard datetime.

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21-Oct-19 15:59','%y-%b-%d %H:%i') AS d;
+---------------------+
| d                   |
+---------------------+
| 2021-10-19 15:59:00 |
+---------------------+

mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21-Oct-19 15:59','%y-%b-%d %H:%i') + INTERVAL 3 DAY AS d;
+---------------------+
| d                   |
+---------------------+
| 2021-10-22 15:59:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to do the date_format after adding the interval :

```
SELECT date_format(now() + interval 3 day, '%d-%b-%y %H:%i') ;
```